# Pong game in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented, classes, helper, pygame

I'm writing a pong game in Python and I created classes for the game objects.

The top level class is `Object`, and `Ball` and `Paddle` inherit from it. And `ComputerPaddle` is a child class of `Paddle`.

```
# classes.py
# 3/19/2013

import pygame
import random

# Paddle properties
PADDLE_WIDTH = 25
PADDLE_HEIGHT = 100
PADDLE_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)
PADDLE_SPEED = 6


# Ball properties
BALL_RADIUS = 20
BALL_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)
BALL_INITIAL_VX = -5
BALL_INITIAL_VY = -5


# Base object class
class Object:

    # Initializes the object with coordinates, size and color
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0
        self.color = color


    # Updates object by moving it and checking if it's in screen range
    def update(self, screenWidth, screenHeight):
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy

        if self.x < 0: self.x = 0
        if self.y < 0: self.y = 0
        if self.x > screenWidth - self.w: self.x = screenWidth - self.w
        if self.y > screenHeight - self.h: self.y = screenHeight - self.h


    # Must be implemented by child classes
    def draw(self, surface):
        pass


    # Returns whether object collides with another object (rectangular collision detection)
    def collides(self, obj):
        return self.y < obj.y + obj.h and self.y + self.h > obj.y and self.x < obj.x + obj.w and self.x + self.w > obj.x


    # Called when object collides with anoher object, must be implemented by child classes
    def onCollide(self, obj):
        pass


# Paddle class  
class Paddle(Object):

    # Initializes Paddle object
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Paddle, self).__init__(x, y, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT, PADDLE_COLOR)

    # Draws paddle with a rectangle
    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))

    # Moves paddle up
    def moveUp(self):
        self.vy -= PADDLE_SPEED

    # Moves paddle down
    def moveDown(self):
        self.vy = PADDLE_SPEED

    # Stops moving the paddle
    def stopMoving(self):
        self.vy = 0


# ComputerPaddle class
class ComputerPaddle(Paddle):

    # Initializes ComputerPaddle object
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(ComputerPaddle, self).__init__(x, y)

    # Adjust Y-velocity based on speed and direction of ball
    def update(self, ball, screenWidth, screenHeight):
        super(ComputerPaddle, self).update(screenWidth, screenHeight)

        if ball.vx < 0: 
            self.stopMoving()
            return

        ballX = ball.x
        ballY = ball.y
        ballVX = ball.vx
        ballVY = ball.vy

        while ballX + ball.w < self.x:
            ballX += ballVX
            ballY += ballVY
            if ballY < 0 or ballY > screenHeight - ball.h: ballVY = -ballVY

        if ballY > self.y + self.h: self.moveDown()
        elif ballY + ball.h < self.y: self.moveUp()
        else: self.stopMoving()


# Ball class
class Ball(Object):

    # Initializes the Ball object along with initial velocities
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Ball, self).__init__(x, y, BALL_RADIUS, BALL_RADIUS, BALL_COLOR)
        self.startX = x
        self.startY = y
        self.vx = BALL_INITIAL_VX
        self.vy = BALL_INITIAL_VY


    # Updates the ball object, if it hits screen edge then negate velocity
    def update(self, screenWidth, screenHeight):
        super(Ball, self).update(screenWidth, screenHeight)

        if self.x == 0 or self.x == screenWidth - self.w: self.vx = -self.vx
        if self.y == 0 or self.y == screenHeight - self.h: self.vy = -self.vy


    # Resets the ball back to its initial coordinates
    def reset(self):
        self.x = self.startX
        self.y = self.startY
        self.vx = BALL_INITIAL_VX
        self.vy = BALL_INITIAL_VY

    # Draws a circle onto screen to represent the ball
    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.circle(surface, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.w)


    # If ball collides with another object, then negate both velocities by a random amount
    def onCollide(self, obj): 

        # If ball is "inside" of paddle, then reposition it so it's just outside the paddle
        if self.x < obj.x + obj.w: self.x = obj.x + obj.w
        elif self.x + self.w > obj.x: self.x = obj.x - self.w
        if self.y < obj.y + obj.h: self.y = obj.y + obj.h
        elif self.y + self.h > obj.y: self.y = obj.y - self.h

        rx = int(random.uniform(-3, 5))
        ry = int(random.uniform(-2, 4))

        self.vx = -self.vx + rx
        self.vy = -self.vy + ry
```

Any ideas how to make this code better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using 4 different fields to keep track of your object's position and size, I suggest you just use a [`Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

```
def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, color):
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0
        self.color = color
```

This way, you can simplify your code a lot.

**Example:** [*Collision detection*](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.colliderect)

```
def collides(self, obj):
        return self.y < obj.y + obj.h and self.y + self.h > obj.y and self.x < obj.x + obj.w and self.x + self.w > obj.x
```

just becomes:

```
def collides(self, obj):
    return self.rect.colliderect(obj.rect)
```

**Example:** [movement](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.move_ip) and [bounds checking](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.clamp_ip)

```
def update(self, screenWidth, screenHeight):
    self.x += self.vx
    self.y += self.vy

    if self.x < 0: self.x = 0
    if self.y < 0: self.y = 0
    if self.x > screenWidth - self.w: self.x = screenWidth - self.w
    if self.y > screenHeight - self.h: self.y = screenHeight - self.h
```

can be rewritten as:

```
def update(self, screenWidth, screenHeight):    
    self.rect.move_ip(self.vx, self.vy)
    self.rect.clamp_ip(Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
```

**Example:** [*drawing*](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect)

```
def draw(self, surface):
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
```

becomes

```
def draw(self, surface):
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, self.rect)
```

Also, I probably wouldn't name a class `Object`, since there's already the `object` class.

Otherwise, I think your code is fine so far.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to move the BALL and PADDLE properties to class attributes:

```
# I wouldn't call your base class Object, as already noted
class Ball(Thing):
    radius = 20
    color = (0, 0, 0)
```

Then you can refer to `Ball.radius` whenever you need it. I'd use this approach because it would encapsulate data about the objects within their class definitions, and it would make it easier to use this as a module later -- you wouldn't need to use `from Things import Ball, BALL_RADIUS, BALL_COLOR`, just `from Things import Ball`.

Another suggestion:
Unless you're using the BALL_INITIAL_V values elsewhere, or want to change them on the fly, I would just use them in the `__init__` methods:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.Vx = -5
    self.Vy = -5
```